# Repeated prime factors

Tags: prime-factorization

For $n\geqslant3$ integer, do all numbers in the form $$n^2-3n+1$$ have unique prime factors? In other words, if these numbers are written in prime factor form, are all indices of the primes in the form $1$?
 I am not sure if this is true,. If this is actually true, is there a proof for it?
What I have done:

Let's first let $\ f(n) = n^2-3n+1$.
 For example, $f(64)=3905$. Amazingly, $3905$ has primes $5$, $11$ and $71$, which corresponds to $f(4)$, $f(5)$ and $f(10)$. Since $f(n)$ lies between $(n-2)^2$ and $(n-1)^2$ for $n\geqslant4$, all $f(n)$ are not perfect squares. So, if it is possible to prove that all composite $f(n)$ have their prime factors from prime $f(n)$ (which is quite possible), this question is done.
Moreover can I generalise that: If any polynomial with integral coefficients $p(n)$ suffices that $p(n)$ is not the power of an integer for all integers $n$, then $p(n)$ in prime factor form cannot have any repeated prime factors?

Comment: In a word, no. Given an odd prime $p\mid n^2-3n+1$ then $p^2\mid m^2-3m+1$ for some $m.$

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that for $n=38$,
$$n^2-3n+1=1331=11^3.$$

Comment: Thanks. I still have two remaining questions:1) Is f(n) not a square for all $n\geqslant4$? and, 2) As $11=f(5)$, are all prime factors of $f(n)$ in the form $f(k)$?